# Calculating new positions for points on a 2D plane that has moved

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, plane-geometry

I have a 2D plane, with few points on it. Coordinates for all points are known.
The black plane is basically a piece of paper and the points are holes in it. I then take the black plane and rotate it by 180 degrees on the A axis, then also move it around a bit (how much is not known) and then rotate it on the vertical axis (how much is not known) to end up in the final position that can be seen at the bottom of the drawing (the plane is still 2D and flat).
I now manually measure the new coordinates for the red and blue points, so now I know their coordinates and also how much they moved on the A,B axes relative to their previous position.

With all this information, how do I calculate the new coordinates of the remaining two points?
(In case this can't be done with just knowing new coordinates of two points, I can add a third one)

Excuse the crude drawing.

[image]

Could this be solved by using something like a 2d matrix?

I take the positions of the red, blue and one of the black points

```
|x1,x2,x3|
|y1,y2,y3|

|6,10,7|
|7,4,5|
```

And have a matrix representing a triangle.

Then after I moved and rotated the the triangle I have these known values:

```
|x1,x2,x3|
|y1,y2,y3|

|7,12,?|
|4,6,?|
```

How to calculate those two missing numbers in this new matrix, so the shape of the triangle remains unchanged ?

Comment: There is certainly enough information to determine the other points. There are only two ways to position the black rectangle in the second picture so that its red and blue dots are in the positions shown: one way when it is flipped over, and one way when it is not flipped over. Since you specified that the rectangle is flipped over, that leaves only one way. The question now is how comfortable you are with vectors, dot products, transformation matrices, and other tools someone might possible bring to bear on this problem.

Comment: Well, I was hoping this could be reduced to some sort of equation where I can plug the numbers into and get the needed result. (I am making a program that will adjust positions of points in a gcode file, which will then be fed to a CNC router that will cut holes into a part, and i need to rotate the part like i described. Which is why I need this equation in order to calculate the positions of the drill holes when the part is flipped and moved. Just to be clear why I am asking for this.)

Comment: Does your programming language support algebraic operations like Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)? If so, I think that the problem is easy to solve!

Comment: It's just c# so probably yes, or if not i can likely just get a library for it.

Comment: If your input data were as accurate as your CNC router then I don't think you would need to worry about techniques like SVD; you could fairly easily construct the necessary matrix by a little trig and some $2\times2$ matrix multiplication. A decent math library should be good enough. But you actually have points exactly $5$ units apart in the first figure and $5.385$ units apart in the second figure, which is a pretty big stretch for an object that's supposed to only have been moved around.

Comment: If the main thing is the relative positions of the four points rather than the exact position and orientation of the black rectangle then I think you can still do some fairly simple math to work out the coordinates (with the help of a math library). It depends on what you really want to do here.

Comment: @DavidK can you elaborate on the simple trig solution? Basically the use case is really simple, I know original coordinates of the two points, then i flip the piece of wood over in the mill, locate the two points again and then i need to use that to calculate new positions of all other drill holes for the mill to make, since i flipped over and move the wood so the points need to be offset correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by the OP, the transformation done to the points consists on a [2D reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_and_reflections_in_two_dimensions) and a translation. Thus, we seek to find a reflection matrix $R$, and a translation vector $t$.

If we denote, for an observation $i$, the coordinates of a point before the transfomation as $p_i$ and the points after the transformation as $q_i$, then $R$ and $t$ should satisfy the following:
$$ 
q_i = R\,p_i + t 
$$
However, since the coordinates of the points are measurements, they are subjected to noise. Hence, we can't get a perfect transformation and we will have some error. Thereby, the previous expression will present some error $\varepsilon_i$:
$$ 
\varepsilon_i = q_i - (R\,p_i + t )
$$

If we choose to minimize the sum of squared errors, i.e.:
$$
R, t = \arg\min_{R,\,t} \sum_{i=1}^n \Vert\varepsilon_i\Vert^2
$$
corresponding to the $n$ observations (2 in the OP's problem), then a closed-form solution is derived in "[Least-squares estimation of transformation parameters between two point patterns, S. Umeyama](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs273/refs/umeyama.pdf)", at equations 34-43.

However, since we are interested in a reflection, instead of a rotation, then equations 39 and 43 should be reversed, to ensure a reflection instead of a rotation.

Following this procedure we would reach the following transformation:
$$ 
R = \begin{bmatrix}
0.96561576 & -0.25997347\\
-0.25997347 & -0.96561576
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad
%
t = \begin{bmatrix}
3.20492804 \\
12.39067446
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Graphically:
[image]

In case it is useful, here is the python code that I used to get the previous result (I'm sorry that I'm not used to c#). I've tried to comment each step. For clarity, the matrix/vector dimensions are indicated in a comment to the right of them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# measured prior to the transformation.
X = np.array([
    [6.0, 10.0], 
    [7.0, 4.0]
    ]) # (2, 2)
# measured after the transformation.
Y = np.array([[7.0, 12.0], 
              [4.0, 6.0]]) # (2, 2)

# get centers of mass in the prior and post configuration.
centroid_x = X.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True) # (2, 1)
centroid_y = Y.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True) # (2, 1)

# sample cross-covariance.
n = 2 # we have only two samples (points)
cov_xy = (Y - centroid_y) @ (X - centroid_x).T / n # (2, 2)

# svd.
U, d, Vt = np.linalg.svd(cov_xy) # (2, 2), (2,), (2, 2) 

# some useful values for later.
UV_det = np.linalg.det(U @ Vt) # float
cov_det = np.linalg.det(cov_xy) # float
cov_rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(cov_xy) # int

# ensure non-degenerate case.
if cov_rank < 1:
    raise ValueError

# ensure reflection instead of rotation.
S = np.eye(2) # (2, 2)
if (cov_rank==1 and UV_det>0) or (cov_rank>1 and cov_det>0):
    S[1, 1] = -1 # set bottom-right element of S to -1.
    
# estimate transformation.
R = U @ S @ Vt # (2, 2)
t = centroid_y - R.dot(centroid_x) # (2, 1)

# visualize and test with the other points.
X_other = np.array([
    [7.0, 9.0], 
    [5.0, 6.0]
    ]) # (2, 2)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

# plot points prior to the transformation and their coords.
axes[0].scatter(X[0], X[1], c=['r', 'b'], s=50)
axes[0].scatter(X_other[0], X_other[1], c='k', s=50)

# plot points after the transformation and their coords.
Y_ = R.dot(X) + t
Y_other = R.dot(X_other) + t

axes[1].scatter(Y_[0], Y_[1], c=['r', 'b'], s=50)
axes[1].scatter(Y[0], Y[1], c=['r', 'b'], s=50, alpha=0.5)
axes[1].scatter(Y_other[0], Y_other[1], c='k', s=50)

# annotations.
for x in np.concatenate((X.T, X_other.T)):
    axes[0].annotate(f'{tuple(x.astype(int))}', x)
    
for y in np.concatenate((Y_.T, Y_other.T)):
    axes[1].annotate(f'{tuple(np.round(y, 1))}', y)

# style.
axes[0].set(
    xlim=(1, 13),
    ylim=(1, 9),
    xticks=np.arange(1, 14, 2),
    yticks=np.arange(1, 10, 2),
    aspect='equal',
    title='before'
    )

axes[1].set(
    xlim=(1, 13),
    ylim=(1, 9),
    xticks=np.arange(1, 14, 2),
    yticks=np.arange(1, 10, 2),
    aspect='equal',
    title='after'
    )
# axes[0].grid(True)
# axes[1].grid(True)
```

---

**Edit**

When doing a reflection or not is known before hand, this alternative code can be used

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# specify if a reflection is done.
reflection_done = False

# measured prior to the transformation.
X = np.array([
    [2.0, 4.0], 
    [2.0, 1.0]
    ]) # (2, 2)
# measured after the transformation.
Y = np.array([[3.0, 5.0], 
              [2.0, 1.0]]) # (2, 2)

# get centers of mass in the prior and post configuration.
centroid_x = X.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True) # (2, 1)
centroid_y = Y.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True) # (2, 1)

# sample cross-covariance.
n = 2 # we have only two samples (points)
cov_xy = (Y - centroid_y) @ (X - centroid_x).T / n # (2, 2)

# svd.
U, d, Vt = np.linalg.svd(cov_xy) # (2, 2), (2,), (2, 2) 

# some useful values for later.
UV_det = np.linalg.det(U @ Vt) # float
cov_det = np.linalg.det(cov_xy) # float
cov_rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(cov_xy) # int

# ensure non-degenerate case.
if cov_rank < 1:
    raise ValueError

# ensure the correct transformation.
S = np.eye(2) # (2, 2)
if reflection_done: 
    if (cov_rank==1 and UV_det>0) or (cov_rank>1 and cov_det>0):
        S[1, 1] = -1 # set bottom-right element of S to -1.
else:
    if (cov_rank==1 and UV_det<0) or (cov_rank>1 and cov_det<0):
        S[1, 1] = -1
    
# estimate transformation.
R = U @ S @ Vt # (2, 2)
t = centroid_y - R.dot(centroid_x) # (2, 1)

# visualize and test with the other points.
X_other = np.array([
    [3.0, 7.0, 9.0], 
    [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
    ]) # (2, 2)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

# plot points prior to the transformation and their coords.
axes[0].scatter(X[0], X[1], c=['r', 'b'], s=50)
axes[0].scatter(X_other[0], X_other[1], c='k', s=50)

# plot points after the transformation and their coords.
Y_ = R.dot(X) + t
Y_other = R.dot(X_other) + t

axes[1].scatter(Y_[0], Y_[1], c=['r', 'b'], s=50)
axes[1].scatter(Y[0], Y[1], c=['r', 'b'], s=50, alpha=0.5)
axes[1].scatter(Y_other[0], Y_other[1], c='k', s=50)

# annotations.
for x in np.concatenate((X.T, X_other.T)):
    axes[0].annotate(f'{tuple(x.astype(int))}', x)
    
for y in np.concatenate((Y_.T, Y_other.T)):
    axes[1].annotate(f'{tuple(np.round(y, 1))}', y)

# style.
get_xlim = lambda axes: (
    min(axes[0].dataLim.xmin, axes[1].dataLim.xmin) - 1, 
    max(axes[0].dataLim.xmax, axes[1].dataLim.xmax) + 1)
get_ylim = lambda axes: (
    min(axes[0].dataLim.ymin, axes[1].dataLim.ymin) - 1, 
    max(axes[0].dataLim.ymax, axes[1].dataLim.ymax) + 1)

axes[0].set(
    xlim=get_xlim(axes),
    ylim=get_ylim(axes),
    # xticks=np.arange(1, 14, 2),
    # yticks=np.arange(1, 10, 2),
    aspect='equal',
    title='before'
    )

axes[1].set(
    xlim=get_xlim(axes),
    ylim=get_ylim(axes),
    # xticks=np.arange(1, 14, 2),
    # yticks=np.arange(1, 10, 2),
    aspect='equal',
    title='after'
    )
# axes[0].grid(True)
# axes[1].grid(True)
```

Comment: Tried running it, but I am getting strange results. If i for example change the starting red and blue point coordinates to 2,2 and 4,1 and add a black point at 3,4,  then move the red and blue points +1 on x axis, so 3,1 and  5,1, i get 2,0 as new coordinates for the black point from the python code,  if i then change original black point coords from 3,4 to 4,4, (with same red and blue points coords) i would expect new black point coords  to be 3,0 since i only moved it by +1 on x axis, but instead i get 2.6, -0,8. Maybe i'm using it wrong?

Comment: @Askerman That happens because a flip was not done in that transformation (only a translation is done). The code I first posted assumed that a reflection (flip) is done, so it won't work if the points only experiment a translation (or a rotation + translation). If this fact is known before hand (if a reflection is done or not), the code can be fixed so that it outputs the correct transformation. I have added code in case that this can be specified at the beginning.

Comment: You are correct! I forgot to flip the points, I will try test it again, with the correctly flipped points.

Comment: Finally got around to trying it out properly and it seems to be working properly. Thanks! I have one last question (i'm not that experienced with python), how would that first python code look like if i wanted to run it on many thousands of coordinates? (red and blue points are always same coords) (and without the graphical output, just array [1,2] output is fine) I tried running it in a loop and it works on small amount of points, but anything in thousands it eventually fails with "RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop" probably memory leak or something i am not seeing.

Comment: @Askerman Great to know! Regarding the question, how do you load the coordinates to test? via a txt/csv file? I think this should be the only thing to be modified within the code. On the other hand, what is the line of code that causes the error you mentioned?

Comment: I managed to figure it out, i just removed the pyplot stuff, that seemed to be using up all the resources and now it works on lots of points no problem. So it's all good now.